# question about sample tech

Tags: raytracing

I am working on a ray tracer.
It's on 
[tls.googlecode.com](http://tls.googlecode.com)

I can find much noise in the first image when I look close.
My question is: is it the normal behaviour for jittered sampler?

some info:The first image is rendered in 1024 samples/pixel (ambient occlusion), Jittered Sampler. And, there is not much difference when I rendered it in 256 samples/pixel.

the source code is in the sampler.h/sampler.cc, which is short.
and any comments on other part of this ray tracer are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me it doesn't look like noise from sampling but rather like there are problems in the ray/triangle intersection logic ("surface acne") which gets masked by the anti-aliasing through oversampling. Are you adding a proper epsilon to your ray's starting point when firing secondary/shadow rays?

Comment: I do give the ray's starting point a eps. Or there will be much strange strip on the floor plane. However I will consider your suggestion and try some greater eps. Thanks.